# ASP.NET: How can I configure the get and set of an object that belongs to a custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I configure the get and set of an object that belongs to a custom class?

I have the following situation (and it’s not working):

```
public class SurveyETA
{
    public static string Question1 { get; set; }
    public static string Question2 { get; set; }
    public static string Question3 { get; set; }
    public static string Question4 { get; set; }
    public static string Question5 { get; set; }
    public static string Question6 { get; set; }
}

public static SurveyETA RespondentETA = new SurveyETA()
{
  Question1 {
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["RespondentQ1"] == null ? "" : HttpContext.Current.Session["jSession326"].ToString();}
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["RespondentQ1"] = value; }}
};
```

My intention is that this object has properties whose content is unique and specific to each user. If I only use a static instance, what happens is that all users share the content.

Comment: I find your question quite confusing. I'm not really sure what your goal is or what your problem is. I'm not really sure how you're even accessing `HttpContext` from a `static` context, since normally you would inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into a registered service (which can be a singleton if desirable). Can you possibly try to give more information about your question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information here to answer your particular question about your particular situation.

That said, I can attempt to make some assumptions about what you may want to consider based on what you're saying.

You talk about having individual users. Where are those users stored? If they're stored in a database, then you can use queries against that database to return information that is specific to those users.

The specific information you have about those users will also be stored in your database, and that information will be associated with those users through the user id for each user (among other things. This is a *very* high level overview of how this works).

TL;DR:

Query whatever database storage mechanism you're using to get the information you need for each user. Return that information and associate it with an instance of your SurveyETA class.

Comment: Thanks T-Rev, DiplomacyNotWar!
The APP is a short survey, no database, only a XML, by user I refer to windows username. The issue is that the answers are saved until they reach the end in the properties of RespondentETA, so if at the same time 2 people use the app, they share the info in this object:i.e. if USER A is in question3, and in memory are saved question1 and question2, if a USER B enters, he replaces the info USER A of those two q, before USER A reaches the end and it is saved in the XML. Therefore i'm trying to save the info in the session and not in statics variables.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need a static variable at all for what you're doing. I'm not a web developer, but as far as I know Session is specific to a particular user, so there shouldn't be any reason why you can't just save this information in the session as they respond to the survey.

Comment: Also, @DiplomacyNotWar is right, you should be using the IHttpContextAccessor to access the Session values in the HttpContext. You can inject that class into your controller / page.

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-get-httpcontext-asp-net-core

Note: If your project is in .Net 6, and you're using the new process for your project then you won't have a ConfigureServices() method. You'd just have "builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor()" somewhere after your CreateBuilder() call.